# Spark POST returns 404 not found seemingly-arbitrarily

Tags: javascript, java, post, http-status-code-404

Spark has been acting weird lately. I have a button which when clicked calls a POST method with some query parameters:

```
post("/test", (request, response) -> {

    model.put("reason", "some reason here");
    ...

    LOG.info("Returning from /test with reason: " + model.get("reason")); 
    // the above line always executes and always prints the correct output (never 404)

    return new ModelAndView(model, "test.vtl");
}, new VelocityTemplateEngine());
```

The file `test.vtl` contains only this: `$reason`
(which is used in the JS code below to show an alert with the contents of the `reason` key in the `model` map).

JS relevant code:

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", "/test", true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

var params = "file=" + file + "&searchStr=" + searchStr;

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlHttp.send(params);
```

When I click it, sometimes it work perfectly, and when I click again I get a 404 Not Found with:

> MatcherFilter:152 - The requested route [/test] has not been mapped in Spark

This happens in a matter of seconds. I click - it works - I click again if fails - again it fails - again it fails - again it suddenly succeeds...

How can that be?

P.s. I have logging inside the `post` request, so I know Spark is actually accessing it. But it is not returning from it. Does this perhaps have to do with the code *inside* the `post` that suddenly raises the 404 (I am not accessing other pages from it though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be 2 possible answers to this (*why* do they solve is a different question):

1. Adding a `Thread.sleep(250); // or even lower`.
2. Changing the request to `GET`.

I could not find what is the root cause of these arbitrary failures, but ended up choosing option #2.